# How to invoke webbrowser from cgi script?

Tags: python, linux, cgi, webbrowser-control

My cgi script is as follows on a Linux system with Firefox and Chrome browsers: Assume that it is a PDF file only. I need to display image files also in a browser. Not able to trace the bug.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
###################################################
# File should be searched on server and displayed
# in the browser
###################################################
import cgi
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()
import StringIO
import sys
import os,glob
import subprocess
import webbrowser

def check_file_extension(display_file):
     input_file = display_file
     nm,file_extension = os.path.splitext(display_file)
     return file_extension

print "Content-type: text/html\n"
responseStr = "<html> %s </html>"
print "<pre>"

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
webbrowser.open_new_tab("file:///home/Documents/postgresql.pdf")       

file_nm = ''
nm =''
path = '/home/Documents'
not_found = 0

if form.has_key("file1"):
     file_nm = form["file1"].value

for f in next(os.walk(path))[2]:
     if str(f) == str(file_nm).strip():
         not_found = 0
         print 'Found file: ' + f
         type_of_file = check_file_extension(f) #TODO: Based on extension, change  content type headers for display
         absolute_path_of_file = os.path.join(path, f)
         file_url = 'file://'+absolute_path_of_file
         print '<a href='+file_url+'>'+ absolute_path_of_file+'</a>'
         try:
            pdf1 = open(absolute_path_of_file,'rb').read()
            print "Content-type: application/pdf\n"
            print pdf1 
            break
         except Exception,e:
            print e 
     else:
         not_found = 1

if not_found == 1:
     print "%s" % str(file_nm) + " not found"

print "%s" % file_nm
print "</pre>"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited my code to work this way:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import os
import cgi
import cgitb 
cgitb.enable()
import sys

def check_file_extension(display_file):
    input_file = display_file
    nm,file_extension = os.path.splitext(display_file)
    return file_extension

form = cgi.FieldStorage()

type_of_file =''
file_nm = ''
nm =''
path = '/home/shantala/Documents'
not_found = 0

if form.has_key("file1"):
    file_nm = form["file1"].value

for f in next(os.walk(path))[2]:
    if str(f) == str(file_nm).strip():
        not_found = 0
        absolute_path_of_file = os.path.join(path, f)
        type_of_file = check_file_extension(absolute_path_of_file)
        if type_of_file == '.pdf':
            file_read = file(absolute_path_of_file,'rb').read()
            print  'Content-type: application/pdf\n'
            print file_read
        if type_of_file == '.txt':
            file_read = file(absolute_path_of_file,'rb').read()
            print  'Content-type: text/html\n'
            print file_read
        if type_of_file == '.png':
            file_read = file(absolute_path_of_file,'rb').read()
            print  'Content-type: image/png\n'
            print file_read
        if type_of_file == '.pdf':
            file_read = file(absolute_path_of_file,'rb').read()
            print  'Content-type: application/pdf\n'
            print file_read
        if type_of_file == '.JPG':
            file_read = file(absolute_path_of_file,'rb').read()
            print  'Content-type: image/jpg\n'
            print file_read
        if type_of_file == '.bmp':
            file_read = file(absolute_path_of_file,'rb').read()
            print  'Content-type: image/bmp\n'
            print file_read

        break
    else:
        not_found = 1

if not_found == 1:
    pass
    # print "%s" % str(file_nm) + " not found"
```